# Running IntelliJ inspections via Maven/TeamCity

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-2, teamcity

I have a Maven project, and I'm trying to configure TeamCity to run [IntelliJ's inspections](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Inspections) on it. [TeamCity's documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Inspections) refers me to [IntelliJ's documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/index.jsp), but I didn't find anything useful there. Can you refer me to how do you configure it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation was incorrect, you can't reference inspections profile directly from the `pom.xml`. Thanks for noticing, we've fixed it.

In case of the Maven project you need to open it in IDEA, define the inspections profile, export the profile into XML file and commit it into the version control with the project. In the TeamCity Inspections runner settings specify the path to the inspections profile XML file relative to the project root.